# trouble in hangman program in c

Tags: c

in the for loop, and in the if statements, for some reason it goes through both if statements even though they are the opposite of each other and i dont know why it is doing it. I have tried different ways and it still comes out the same way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main ()
{
char secretword[20] = {};
char alphabet[28] = {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "};
char guess[2] = {};
int i = 0, k = 0;
int seclength = 0, alphlength = 0;
int GuessCtr = 6;

printf("You Get six chances to guess all of the letters in a phrase\n");
printf("Enter the secret word/phrase: ");
scanf("%s", &secretword);
seclength = strlen(secretword);
alphlength = strlen(alphabet);
while(GuessCtr != 0)
{
    printf("Past guesses: ");
    for(i = 0; i < alphlength; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", alphabet[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Guess a character: ");
    scanf("%s", &guess);
    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0; i < seclength; i++)
    {
            if(secretword[i] == guess[0])
            {
                secretword[i] = '*';
            }
            /*else
            {
                GuessCtr--;
                printf("You missed - you have %d wrong guesses left!", GuessCtr);
            }*/
            if(secretword[i] != guess[0])
            {
                GuessCtr--;
                printf("You missed - you have %d wrong guesses left!", GuessCtr);
            }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < seclength; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", secretword[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0; i < alphlength; i++)
    {
        if(alphabet[i] == guess[0])
        {
            alphabet[i] = '*';
        }
    }
}
printf("You suck!");


return 0;
```

}

Comment: Try codereview or distil this to a minimal problem.

Comment: You are changing `secretword` in the first `if`. Maybe the second `if` should be `else`.

Comment: Watch out! You are using the scanf with the wrong argument! you are passing the pointer to a pointer and you want to pass a pointer. This happens a few times...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the body of the first `if` statement changes the variable that it tested, and the second one will test again. When the second `if` is evaluated, the variable has a different value than it did the first time.

To fix this, you need to use `else`, so the condition is "remembered" from the first time:

```
        if(secretword[i] == guess[0])
        {
            secretword[i] = '*';
        }
        else
        {
            GuessCtr--;
            printf("You missed - you have %d wrong guesses left!", GuessCtr);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are being misled about what is wrong with the program.

Since this seems like homework, I won't answer the overall situation, but you should carefully inspect this statement to find the error:

```
scanf("%s", &secretword);
```